# Average time Calculation

Tags: c#, excel-2003

i just want the formula to calculate average waiting time depending upon the time difference between the events and number of the events occured............... For example if a customer comes to me at 9:00 am and i issue him a token then i give a token to another customer at 9:07am  and so on...... and thus at the end of the day i want to calculate the average waiting time .................... And is it necessary to know at what time i served the customer in order to calculate the average time................... i want to check avg time for a day or a week or a month or a year or between few days or few weeks or months

Comment: Do you have any VB specific code that you've got problems with? If you are after help with using MS Excel, you should try http://superuser.com, which is more tailored to answering questions about how to use applications. Depending on your spreadsheet, the =AVERAGE() function may be all that you need. Good luck.

Comment: this i need to implemeny using c# not  in excel

Answer (score 1):

Before you can determine the average time someone waited, you must know when they began waiting (the time when you give them the token) and the time they stopped waiting (the time you served them).  You cannot determine the average wait time by only knowing when you can give hand out tokens (baring having flow data and the like, but if you have that, you certainly will also record service time).

Until you have the data you need, the answer is there's no way to calculate what you are looking for.